# New functionality: convert close votes

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Close votes can be retracted from a question, but after that, no more close votes can be cast on that particular question.

I understand that voting and revoking several times would negatively impact queues and might could create a complicated situation; what I would like to have is the ability to convert close votes.

I was in several times in situation voting to close a question as unclear, and after clarification it was off-topic for some other reason, e.g. not computer / product recommendation.

Also sometimes I'm just clicking too fast and select the wrong reason.

Having the possibility to convert already cast close votes would help to better indicate the reason of closure.

Comment: Not sure why someone DV'd this, its a great idea!

Comment: Yes please! Note that this feature has already [been asked for](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/863/223467) on MSE as far back as 2009, so maybe it's a good idea to try and revive that thread.

Comment: The fact that a user can edit its own question makes it a moving target for flagging. The reviewer should be able to adapt.

Comment: Just to note, this literally is something we'd need to have done on the SE platform as a whole - so its not up to mods to do. Since it was asked.

Comment: Thanks @JourneymanGeek!